# Pandas, compare 2 dataframes in index and column displaced location

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have df1:

```
    filerid usersidid client_op ClientHostID eventSum
0      1       1       5030          6          2
1      1       2       5030          7          1
2      1       3       5030          8          1
```

and df2:

```
    ClientHostID usersidid client_op filerid  eventSum
0        7           2       5030        1          1
1        6           1       5030        1          2
2        8           3       5030        1          1
```

Now, I need to check if the 2 dfs have a matching rows (for instance, I consider the dfs in the example as a match).

The thing is, the rows and the columns swapped places and dataframe.equales() checks if the dfs are **Identical**, including the same orientation of the rows and columns.

I can't reorder the rows and columns, but I'm guarantied that the columns have the same labels.

I tried to use dataframe.isin, but it works on a single label and I need to check for a row match...

Any insight would be appreciated,
Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the simpliest is use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) where is not `on`, so merge on all columns, with [`equals`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.equals.html):

```
print (pd.merge(df1, df2))
   filerid  usersidid  client_op  ClientHostID  eventSum
0        1          1       5030             6         2
1        1          2       5030             7         1
2        1          3       5030             8         1

print (pd.merge(df1, df2).equals(df1))
True
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
for column in df1.columns:

    try:

        if df1[column] == df2[column]:

             print 'match of column %s' %column

     except:

         pass
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You can compare entire dataframe after reindexing.
For example if you know that your usersidid is unique in the dataframe, you can do this:

```
df1.index = df1.usersidid
df2.index = df2.usersidid
df1.shape[0] * df1.shape[1] == (df1 == df2).sum().sum()
```

If this returns a true, the dataframes are identical.

`(df1 == df2).sum().sum()` gives you the number of cells that are equal, `df1.shape[0] * df1.shape[1]` calculates the total amount of cells.

Of course you can also do it the other way around:

```
(df1 != df2).sum().sum()
```

Should return 0